# can you use jquery to see if a target contains a <b> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

so, i have something like this.

```
 var $list = $("div#item");
```

I was looking at :contains in the selector, but i wasnt sure if that applied to markup or if i should do something like:

```
 if($list.find("<b>"))return 1;
 else return 0;
```

Reasoning:  Adding functionality to a program which uses inline tags, and want to maintain structure.

Goal:  if(item contains an inline b, u, i tags) return 1; else return 0;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simplify it down to a single selector `.find("b,i,u")` and return the boolean comparison `length > 0`. If any of the tags `<b><i><u>` are found inside `#item`, the overall length will be `> 0`:

```
return $("#item").find("b,i,u").length > 0;
```

[Proof of concept](http://jsfiddle.net/8Kmqu/)

**Edit**: If you really want a `number` zero or one back instead of the `boolean`, use a ternary:

```
return $("#item").find("b,i,u").length > 0 ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: Or even shorter, `!!$("#item").find("b,i,u").length` :)

Comment: mmm, i know boolean logic, as it would return true or false, but will true and false also be recognized as 1 or 0?  or will i have to make a small adjustment?

Comment: @Fallenreaper You can wrap it in a ternary. Edited above.

Answer (score 5):

```
return document.querySelector("#item b, #item u, #item i") ? 1 : 0;
```

No need for jQuery.

If you need to support browsers IE7 and older, try this:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('item');
return elem.getElementsByTagName('b').length
     + elem.getElementsByTagName('i').length
     + elem.getElementsByTagName('u').length == 0 ? 0 : 1;
```

Comment: Probably want to use `===` instead of `==`

Comment: @DavidHoerster Why? What can a sum of lengths be other than an integer? What can a literal `0` be other than an integer?

Answer (score 4):

perhaps use the `.has()` method.

```
$('li').has('ul')
```

[jquery has](http://api.jquery.com/has/)

Comment: +1 for has method which I didn't know of, but it still returns a jQuery element. However, if you use .has(...).length it will yield 0 or 1 which is the solution the OP was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

you can also do that with .has() function

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's the most efficient, but I would use `.find` for this.

```
function hasInline(targetElement) { 
  return ($(targetElement).find('b,u,i').length > 0); 
}
```

I'd also recommend expanding the function so you could specify whatever inline tags you wanted to check, like so:

```
// NOTE: This will return true if the element has ANY of the tags provided.
function hasInlineTags(targetElement, listOfTags) { 
  return ($(targetElement).find(listOfTags.join(',')).length > 0); 
}

// Call it with whatever tags you want.
hasInlineTags($("div#item"), ['b','u','i']);
```

Comment: Sorry for repetition of `.find` recommendations above. Answers were posted while I was writing mine and I didn't load them before submission.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using jQuery:

```
var styleElements = $('b,u,i', $list)
```

Use:

```
return (styleElements.length) ? 1 : 0;
```